# Получить список доступных вариантов событий гема Audited

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Всем привет!
В приложении установлен гем Audited. 
Занимаюсь реализацией страницы со всеми аудитами. Нужно добавить фильтр по полю "action". 
Вопрос состоит в том, как через гем Audited можно получить список доступных вариантов поля "action"? 
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно выбрать уникальные значения поля action из модели, которую в приложение добавляет гем. Один из вариантов:

```
Audited::Audit.distinct.pluck(:action)
```